# How invoke Action method by variable on Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, action

How can I invoke action method by variable? To explain better, this code works

```
<s:action name="indexController!loadData" executeResult="false" />
```

... But this other one doesn't work

```
<s:action var="mainController" name="indexController" />    
<s:action name="mainController!loadData" executeResult="false" />
```

... I also tried

```
<s:action var="mainController" name="indexController" />    
<s:action name="#mainController!loadData" executeResult="false" />
```

But it doesn't work too. I need the second mode, because I must switch action dynamically on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **name** attribute you need to force the **OGNL evaluation** with `%{}`

Try using Set tag instead of Action tag

```
<s:set var="mainController" value="%{'indexController'}" />   
<s:action name="%{#mainController}!loadData" executeResult="false" />
```

or in alternative

```
<s:set var="mainController" value="%{'indexController!loadData'}" />
<s:action name="%{#mainController}" executeResult="false" />
```

or

```
<c:set var="mainController" value="indexController" scope="request"/>
<s:action name="%{#request.mainController}!loadData" executeResult="false" />
```

Comment: I try as you indicated, but struts 2 throws this Exception

`ERROR [org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent] Could not execute action: //fi.fpf.mvc.controller.IndexController@1f4f294!loadData: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [fi.fpf.mvc.controller.IndexController@1f4f294] associated with context path [/fpf]. - [unknown location]
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185) [:2.3.14.2]`

Comment: Then it worked: `... action name [fi.fpf.mvc.controller.IndexController ...` Now this is *another* problem, probably **namespace-related**. Editing your question by posting your struts.xml may help

Comment: If I write
`<s:action name="indexController!loadData" executeResult="false" />`
It works: I think the problem is in the evaluation of the expression 
%{#mainController}

Comment: Great, It works. I also find another solution by using c taglib. Here the code:

`<c:set var="mainController" value="indexController" scope="request"/>
 <s:action name="%{#request.mainController}!loadData" executeResult="false" />`

Comment: Yes, you can use JSTL too, but i prefer Struts tags. Please remember to accept the answer ;)